# This code was created with Microsoft Library 15.0 but not working on 14.0 and highlighs the "Sub" word?

Tags: excel, vba, dll

Getting an error with it highlighting "Sub OptoRun()" when the user with Microsoft Library 14.0 is trying to run the program in excel.  I created this in 15.0.  Do I need to change it?  How do I know what to change it to?

```
Sub OptoRun()
'
' OptoRun Macro
'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="9061"
'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$2:$Q$200", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$2:$Q$200", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

    Range("priorProjPts").Value = Range("totProjPts").Value - 0.01

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="9061"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to add reference to the Solver add-in. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/functions/using-the-solver-vba-functions).

Comment: ..and `Option Explicit`. Always.